# Drag and Drop not working inside Document Set for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, document-set

we have a SharePoint Online site and we have a document library in it. We are using IE 11 and Chrome for browsing and working on the site.

In this document library we have several folders. Each folder has multiple document sets. We are able to drag and drop files inside the document library (top most level), and also we are able to drag and drop files inside the folders.

However, we are not able to drag and drop files inside the document set.

Any idea on what might be causing this issue? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Tested in my environment,but not reproduce your issue, Drop and Drag in IE11 within a Document set folder, it still working. Is there any error information in your side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolved it by changing the webpart Chrome Property to "None". It worked but still feels weird.